# Days before end of month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the number of days before the end of the month, from a string column representing a date.
I have the following pandas dataframe :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-11-22','2019-11-08','2019-11-30']})
df

         date
0  2019-11-22
1  2019-11-08
2  2019-11-30
```

I would like the following output :

```py
 df
         date  days_end_month
0  2019-11-22               8
1  2019-11-08              22
2  2019-11-30               0
```

The package `pd.tseries.MonthEnd` with `rollforward` seemed a good pick, but I can't figure out how to use it to transform a whole column.

Comment: This could make it : 
```df['days_end_month'] = pd.Period(df['date']).days_in_month - df['date'].dt.day```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract all days of month created by [`Series.dt.daysinmonth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth.html) with days extracted by [`Series.dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['days_end_month'] = df['date'].dt.daysinmonth - df['date'].dt.day
```

Or use [`offsets.MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html), subtract and convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['days_end_month'] = (df['date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) - df['date']).dt.days
```

---

```
print (df)
        date  days_end_month
0 2019-11-22               8
1 2019-11-08              22
2 2019-11-30               0
```